# Is $\frac{\alpha}{\|\alpha\|}$ a path that starting at $ \frac{x}{\|x\|}$ and ending at $\frac{y}{\|y\|}$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

> Let $\alpha$ be a path in $\mathbb{R^2}$ starting at $x$ and ending at $y$. Is $\displaystyle \frac{\alpha}{\|\alpha\|}$ a path that starting at $\displaystyle \frac{x}{\|x\|}$ and ending at $\displaystyle \frac{y}{\|y\|}$ ?

EDIT: Assume $\alpha$ does not contain $0$.

I think the answer is YES.

So, $\alpha:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ is continuous and $\alpha(0)=x$ and $\alpha(1)=y$. I can show that $\displaystyle \frac{\alpha}{\|\alpha\|}(0)=\frac{x}{\|x\|}$ and $\displaystyle \frac{\alpha}{\|\alpha\|}(1)=\frac{y}{\|y\|}$. But, how do I prove that $\displaystyle \frac{\alpha}{\|\alpha\|}$ is continuous? Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Note that $\alpha/\|\alpha\|$ is not defined where $\alpha = 0$

Comment: Can we assume that $\alpha$ is a path in $\Bbb R^2 \setminus\{0\}$?

Comment: Yes. I included an edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes.  Note that $t \mapsto \alpha(t)/\|\alpha(t)\|$ is simply the composition of continuous maps.

- $f(s) = 1/s$ is continuous on $\Bbb R \setminus \{0\}$
- $m(s,t) = st$ is continuous
- $n:x \mapsto \|x\|$ is continuous
- $\alpha/\|\alpha\|(t) = m(\alpha(t),f(n(\alpha(t))))$.